# How can you superimpose circle avatars on top of each other?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am facing this for the first time and I have no options on how to do it. I read many forums and did not find anything like this anywhere. I need to do as in the picture, how can I do it
This is a sample of how it should turn out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpRua.png)

```
    Padding(padding: const  EdgeInsets.only(top: 15), 
     child: Row(
      children: const  [
                                        
      CircleAvatar(
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    radius: 18,
  child: CircleAvatar(
  radius: 16,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/assets/avatar-410658-028235png.png'),
     ),
       ),
                                   
   CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      radius: 18,
      child: CircleAvatar(
   radius: 16,
    backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/assets/avatar-410658-028235png.png'),
       ),
      ),

      CircleAvatar(
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   radius: 18,
 child: CircleAvatar(
     radius: 16,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/assets/avatar-410658-028235png.png'),
  ),
   ),
    
    
     CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   radius: 20,
   child:  CircleAvatar(
  radius: 18, 
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  child: Text('28', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.5, color: Colors.white ),),
   )
     ),
     
    
     Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70)   ,
     child: Text('6 Hours Ago', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.5),)
      ),
        ],
           ),
             ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`You need to wrap your CircleAvatar widget with align widget and set the widthFactor parameter to a double for example.`

```
   Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Align(
                widthFactor: .7,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 18,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 16,
                    backgroundImage:
                        AssetImage('lib/assets/avatar-410658-028235png.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                widthFactor: .7,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 18,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 16,
                    backgroundImage:
                        AssetImage('lib/assets/avatar-410658-028235png.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                widthFactor: .7,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 18,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 16,
                    backgroundImage:
                        AssetImage('lib/assets/avatar-410658-028235png.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                widthFactor: .7,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    radius: 20,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 18,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      child: Text(
                        '28',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.5, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                  child: Text(
                    '6 Hours Ago',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.5),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the stack widget. Read about it here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html